# Zend 1.12 .htaccess seems to not work

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework, netbeans, routes

I've created zend framework project in netbeans, changed my public/.htaccess file like below, but it doesnt work.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

"setenv" doesnt help, i have to manually change *APPLICATION_ENV* to *development* in *public/index.php* where $application is declared. And my hyperlinks dont work well, which is the most important. I want them to use without writing index.php everytime for example route defined in *application.ini* ("/a/b/c/towary-lista.html") i want to use  localhost/projectname/public/a/b/c/towary-lista.html . Of course public is redundant, but i dont think about it now. Thanks for help!

Comment: What specifically is the issue? You just don't get any rewriting? Can you given an example of a rewrite you would expect? With mod_rewrite you can debug by redirecting a page with variables in the URL, e.g. RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?%{ENV:BASE}

Comment: i get error like this (Not Found. The requested URL /zmija/public/zasoby/pokazuj was not found on this server. ).

Comment: And i would like to get the view from specified action in a controller. I handled routing like this:
    resources.router.routes.towary.route = "/a/b/c/towary-lista.html"

    resources.router.routes.towary.defaults.controller = "zasoby"

    
resources.router.routes.towary.defaults.action = "pokazuj"

Comment: Maybe just rewriting module in Apache isn't active? (`a2enmod rewrite`)

Answer (score 0):

Check if modenv
(http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html) is activated in your httpd.conf